# What is the difference between the PS3 and PSP versions of Monster Hunter Tri

Tags: version-differences, monster-hunter-3-tri

Are there any differences between them, And Is there an online mode on the PS3 version?

Comment: The main one is that it's Japanese only; it was never released in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Monster Hunter Tri*** isn't available on the PS3, it was a Wii exclusive. An expanded version (***Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate***) is currently available for the  WiiU and 3DS.

Are you talking about ***Monster Hunter Portable 3rd***? Both versions of that game (PS3 & PSP) were only released in Japan. *The PS3 version is an **HD** remake and re-release of the PSP game.*

*Monster Hunter Portable 3rd* is the third game to be released in the series for **handheld systems**. *Monster Hunter Tri* is the third game in the series for **consoles**. This excludes expanded versions like *Monster Hunter Freedom Unite* or *Monster Hunter G*. This is why both games use some variant of **3** in their naming systems.